# Bash script find certain text in a file.dev and assign it to a variable

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, grep, kernel

I have a file.dev that contains the following:

```
1 DEVICES {
    2            GLOBAL-CONFIG {
    3               framerate = "20000";
    4               subframes = "0";
    5               max_consec_timeouts = "10";
    6               max_total_timeouts = "1000";
    7               schedmode = "Standard";
    8               clustermode = "Standard";
    9           }
    10           IO-DEVICES {
    11            }
    12           COMPUTING-DEVICES {
    13                RT_WORKSTATION FDT-C-XM-0120 = {
    14                    hostname = "FDT-C-XM-0120";
    15                    ipaddress = "fdt-c-XM-0120.fdtel.exter";
    16                    DISPLAYS {
    17                        main = "FDT-C-XM-0120:0.0";
    18                    }
    19                    SCHEDPARAM {
    20                        active = "0";
    21                        framerate = "20000";
    22                        subframes = "0";
    23                        max_consec_timeouts = "10";
    24                        max_total_timeouts = "1000";
    25                    }
    26                }
    27              
    28              RT_HOST fdt-c-agx-0008 = { 
    29                    hostname = "fdt-c-agx-0008";
    30                    ipaddress = "fdt-c-agx-0008";
    31                    SCHEDPARAM {
    32                        active = "0";
    33                        framerate = "20000";
    34                        subframes = "0";
    35                        max_consec_timeouts = "10";
    36                        max_total_timeouts = "1000";
    37                    }
    38                }
    39              
    40    #             RT_HOST fdt-c-agx-0003 = { 
    41    #                    hostname = "fdt-c-agx-0003";
    42    #                   ipaddress = "fdt-c-agx-0003.fdtel.exter";
    43    #                    SCHEDPARAM {
    44    #                        active = "0";
    45    #                        framerate = "20000";
    46    #                        subframes = "0";
    47    #                        max_consec_timeouts = "10";
    48    #                        max_total_timeouts = "1000";
    49    #                    }
    50    #                }
    51            }
    52        }
```

this file is located in a the directory `C:/TechSAT/ADS2/config/file.dev`

As you can see there are three entry for the variable `hostname` `(line 14, 29 and 41)` .

What i'm tying to do is to wrtie a bash script that find only the first entry `(line 14)` and save its value `FDT-C-XM-0120` in a variable like `$hostnameValue = FDT-C-XM-0120` for test purposes.

I actually found a semi-working solution like:

```
var=$(grep -r 'hostname' C:/TechSAT/ADS2/config/devices.dev)
```

However, this prints all matches like

```
         hostname = "FDT-C-VM-0120";
                    hostname = "fdt-c-agx-0008";
#                    hostname = "fdt-c-agx-0003";
```

and in my case the `var` must contain the value of the first match which is `FDT-C-XM-0120`

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a option -m in GNU grep 3.6

Comment: @ctac_ thanks for the command. Yes i found it. However it prints the whole line and would look like `hostname = "FDT-C-VM-0120" ` with the spaces before and i just want the value `FDT-C-VM-0120`

Comment: And what have you try ?

Comment: @ctac_ i've tried the following  `var1=$(grep -r 'hostname' -m1 C:/TechSAT/ADS2/config/devices.dev)` and as already said the output is the whole line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk can do what you want.

```
awk -F'"' '/hostname/{print $2 ; exit}' file.txt
```

Output

```
FDT-C-XM-0120
```

With GNU `grep` and `cut`

```
grep -m1 'hostname' file.txt | cut -d'"' -f2
```

Both solutions is using a double quotes *"* as the delimiter, with `awk` `-F'"'` and with `cut` `-d'"'` the double quotes needs to escaped, either use a `\` or enclose it with a single quote *'*. So it can be written as `-F\"` and `-d\"`

Comment: Thanks alot. it works perfectly. May i ask from where did you set the delimeter regarding awk command to get the desired output  ?

Comment: @Zang322, I have added a short explanation, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the explanation. would be glad if you could vote up my question.

Comment: would be thankful if you could help me here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67359144/edit-file-dev-using-bash-script